# Centralize Eclipse Configuration

Tags: eclipse, configuration, editor

Does anybody have a system that they use to maintain the same eclipse configuration between computers?  How well does it work?

I am getting to a point where I have a reasonable setup to get a new Eclipse installation to the same point as my others, and I miss the emacs functionality of having all your customizations in a centralized store.

I use largely Flex Builder 3, with the Mercurial plug in.  But also use it for anything else that I am developing, so at the moment I am considering doing a re-setup with aptana studio and adding the flex builder plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with the preconfigured distribution, but still want to let your developers choose, which plugins from a restricted set of plugins to install additionally, then its worth to create a company internal update site, which **mirrors selected features** and plugins, so your developers can install them (and only them!).

The [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_sitemap.html) has a full description of how to mirror update sites (from the command line).

Comment: I tried that kind of local mirroring setup (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131704, for a slightly different purpose) but never quite managed to make it work. If you have more details than just the help, feel free to answer my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

We do not have *exactly* a common eclipse configuration but rather a common eclipse **distribution**.

A new developer copy that distribution, and launches it through a custom "eclipse.exe" which:

- calls a script checking if there is any in-house updates I have set up since the last launch (like a new enhanced eclipse.ini, new plugins, new config files, ...)
- calls the real eclipse.exe and actually launches the IDE

That way, all developer have a platform which evolves according to *my common* additions to the global common development system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Eclipse plugin ["Workspace mechanic"](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic) which make you tweak preference to (according to its documentation):

- Create a consistent environment among groups as large as the entire company, your local team, or even among your own many workspaces
- Save time setting up new workspaces
- Create tasks that ensure your favorite new preferences are applied to all your current and future workspaces.

It is compatible almost with every version of Eclipse. It's worth a try.