# Installing bundles from the local file system into Eclipse (via a p2 repository)

Tags: eclipse, tycho, p2

I have a few OSGI bundles that I would like to store in a local P2 repository. I have followed this guide:

https://docs.sonatype.org/display/TYCHO/How+to+make+existing+OSGi+bundles+consumable+by+Tycho

to use eclipsec.exe  to convert the folder with bundles into a p2 repository. The resulting structure is like this:

```
c:\test\repo
c:\test\repo\plugins
c:\test\repo\plugins\my.bundle.jar
c:\test\repo\artifacts.jar
c:\test\repo\content.jar
```

Now I would like to add this repository in eclipse Helios. In the eclipse update manager  I select add an press the "Local..." button where I specify the path to the repo:

```
Name: testRepo
Location: file:/C:/test/repo/
```

I then uncheck "Group items by category" but it just says "There are no items available".

How do I add this local repository to eclipse?

Comment: Hm creating an update site and wrapping my bundles into features which are then added to the update site which can the be build and referenced also works, even though its a bit more time consuming.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131704/is-it-possible-to-make-an-eclipse-p2-provisioning-mechanism-running-locally help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new "Feature project" (New-->other-->plug-in development-->"Feature project")
Then you need to link this to your project from its project properties.

Then you need to create a new "Update Site Project" (there is a link on feature.xml Overview).
Then you need to link this to your project and the feature from its project properties.

then add a new category, and the feature you created in it, then say build and it builds the update site for you...